# Howto mount drive as read-only with fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, read-only

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and everything is working perfectly.

I have a few drives that I use for archive storage, these drives are completly full now and will never be written to again.

I would like to change the mount options in `/etc/fstab` so that they are mounted as read-only at boot.

The drives are encrypted with LUKS and have an ext4 file system.

My current line in `/etc/fstab` for the drive in question looks like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/68271755-703c-48e6-a935-c1237de6b1a8 /mnt/HDD01 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

What do I need to change to make it mount the drive read-only, but leaving everything else as it is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You simply have to add the `ro` mount option, which stands for "read-only".

In `/etc/fstab` entries, mount options are specified in the 4th column of each entry, so you could append it to that one e.g. like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/68271755-703c-48e6-a935-c1237de6b1a8 /mnt/HDD01 auto ro,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

More information can be found by typing [`man fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/fstab) and [`man mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mount).

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey check button on its left. You can learn more about how things work here on Ask Ubuntu by taking the short [tour]. Thanks and welcome here.

Comment: Can I use `UUID=xxxxx` instead of `/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx`?

Comment: @Royi sure, I just used the format that was originally presented in the question. The important thing is to add the `ro` option to an otherwise correct and working line.

Comment: I understood what you did. I just asked if there is a difference in the format to use the `UUID`?

Comment: @Royi Both should work and have the same effect. I am not aware of a difference.