# How to remount the filesystem with read-only permission

Tags: permissions, filesystem, read-only

For some reason, I need to make sure that nobody can change my filesystem.

So i try to remount the `/` with read-only permission.

I've tried `sudo mount -o remount,ro /` but it told me `mount: / is busy`.

How can I do this? BTW, Reboot is acceptable.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this if you are actually using system which is mounted at `/`. I would try to do this from [live session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) of Ubuntu.
BTW: did you try with `sudo`?

Comment: @Qback  Yeah, I `mount` with `sudo`.

Comment: Make the change in the `/etc/fstab` file https://askubuntu.com/questions/839355/howto-mount-drive-as-read-only-with-fstab